# in tcl, how the following foreach statement works?

Tags: foreach, tcl

I have a question about foreach in tcl:

```
foreach id "6 8" {
   #do something here;
}
```

is this `"6 8"` a list? and what does "6 8" mean?

Comment: Tcl's type system is thus: if you use a value as a list, it _is_ a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing to remember is that Tcl doesn't have types, per se, at least not in a way that the user should need to worry about them. Rather, each value is a string and each command tries to treat it as the type of value it needs.

For example:

```
set value "1"
expr {$value + 1} ; # treat $value as a number
lindex $value 0   ; # treat $value as a list
```

For your code, the value `6 8` is being interpreted as a list by the `foreach` command, with the value `6` and `8`. The double quotes around the value just group the content inside them as a single value. They (the dqs) don't signify any specific type (ie, string, list, number).

Comment: To not scare off speed freaks, it worth mentioning that both string and "native" representations are calculated on demand and are cached in the value, so if one piece of code interprets a particular value as an integer, the integer representation is computed and cached, and if another piece of code interprets that same value again as an integer, the cached representation is used right away incurring no reparsing overhead.

Comment: @kostix Very true. When you have a value, it's best to treat it as the same type for it's lifetime or, at the least, don't switch back and forth between treating it as different types. Each time the interpreter needs to figure out "what does this variable mean when interpreted as a list" when you last treated it as an integer (and so on), it costs time. Not a huge amount of time, but it's worth remembering and a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach id "6 8" {
    # do something
}
```

In this context, "6 8" is a list of two elements, *6* and *8*. The loop for assign id first to *6*, enter the loop's body. The next time around, id will be *8* and enter the loop's body. When it runs out of items in the list, the loop exits.